# Multipeer connectivity transfers files however peers do not receive files

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

In my code below I am attempting to send the time as a string across to multiple peers however either the strings are never sent through or my function never runs on the peers side.  here is my code, there are no errors

```
@IBAction func pick(sender: AnyObject) {



    self.presentPicker(sender)


    let now = NSDate()
    let nowData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(now)
    var error : NSError?
    self.session.sendData(nowData, toPeers: self.session.connectedPeers, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Unreliable, error: &error)

    println("sending data")



   /* let formatter = NSDateFormatter()

    //formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)  // you can set GMT time
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone() // or as local time
    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss:SSS"



    formatter.dateFormat = "HHmmssSSS"
    */




    if error != nil {
        print(":( Were sorry there was an error :( please notify/email the developers (mecnewport@gmail.com) about this error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var DestView: ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
        DestView.selectedSong = MPMediaItemCollection()


        }

        // self.updateChat(self.messageField.text, fromPeer: self.peerID)

        // self.startTime.text = ""




}
```

break

```
  func session(session: MCSession!, didReceiveData data: NSData!,
    fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!)  {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            var nowData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)


                // if time_value = startTime

                let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
                //formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)  // you can set GMT time
                formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone() // or as local time
                formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss.SSS"
                var currentTime = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
                println(currentTime)



                //"var Time.delegate"

                var startTime = (nowData as NSString?)!.integerValue + 100
                println(startTime)



                }




        }
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that self.session.connectedPeers is not an empty array?

Comment: I have not declared the array anywhere but I am pretty sure the array exists within the multiplier connectivity framework

Comment: @KeithCoughtrey yes, multipeer connectivity includes the array connectedPeers

Comment: I realise that. My question is, does the array actually confirm that you have connected peers at the time you send your data? If it does not, error will be nil as it successfully sent the data to all (zero) connected peers. If you NSLog("peers=%@",session.connectedPeers) you will see exactly who you are sending to.

Comment: @KeithCoughtrey I added this to my code and received this output peers=(
)
sending data
:( Were sorry there was an error :( please notify/email the developers (@gmail.com) about this error: Optional("Invalid peerIDs parameter")2015-07-11 15:17:51.708 AudioWaves[19642:1060668] peers=(
)
What could this possibly mean?  The peers do say connected in the multipeer connectivity browser